# "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am creating a Django-rest authentication API. However, every time I try to create a user, I get this error. I have tried several solutions here with no success.

HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
"detail": "Method "GET" not allowed."
}

Why? Are there any changes that I should make?

**Here's my Serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import CustomUser

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, cls).get_token(user)
        
        token['fav_color'] = user.fav_color
        return token

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length = 8, write_only= True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
            instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
            
            if password is not None:
                instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

**Here's my Views.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer, MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
# Create your views here.

class ObtainTokenPairWithColorView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = TokenObtainPairSerializer
    
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, render, format = 'json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid:
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 

class HelloWorld(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(data={"hello":"world"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

[The error message that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nln2D.png)

Comment: why is def create inside your meta class in CustomUserSerializer.? Is it a typo while pasting it or is this how your actual code is?

Comment: Anyway the error might be because you have selected GET in the django interface, it should be POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView    
class UserCreateApiView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

replace above code this will work for you